# HOA on-street parking: where is the street adjoining the property?

Tags: hoa

A local HOA (in North Carolina) has these rules about on-street parking:

> Section 13. On-Street Parking. The Owner of each Lot shall provide for adequate parking space on the Lot for vehicles of all types and all other apparatus designed for movement over and upon streets or highways (whether self-propelled or not) and regularly used by the residents of the single-family residence on the Lot. No automobiles, trucks, vans, travel trailers, other trailers or any other apparatus designed for movement over and upon streets or highways (whether self-propelled or not) shall be regularly parked on the streets within or adjoining the Property, and motor vehicles licensed to carry more than two (2) tons shall not be permitted to park overnight or regularly on the streets, driveways or otherwise within the Property, except that Declarant may allow such parking by any such vehicles used in connection with the construction of improvements within the Property. In addition and supplemental to the prohibitions on parking set forth in this Declaration the Board is empowered to promulgate and enforce rules and regulations relating to parking on the streets within or adjoining the Property.

Where is it considered to be "within or adjoining the Property"?

It seems the rules are prohibiting parking on a street that goes through a property, and parking on a street in the part of the street that is adjacent to the property.  Does it not prohibit regular parking a few houses away around the corner on a different street (in the same neighborhood)?

Does it not prohibit regular parking on the same street up a few houses in front of a different property?

Comment: Because Property is capitalized, there is likely a definitions page that says what it means.  Most likely Property means the subdivision or development.

Comment: @ScottDunnington  Earlier I was mistaken. Property is indeed the development.  So it seem the answer is that residents must park all of their vehicles on their lot, and they can not regularly park on the streets of the neighborhood.  Thank you.

Comment: @ScottDunnington, if you'd like to submit an answer based on Property meaning the subdivision I will accept it.